# Creating a View Controller that only appears on first app open

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am creating a View Controller that only appears the first time the user opens the app. I had it working by just pushing the welcome view controller, but then I couldn't get it to push the normalViewController when the user was done in the welcomeViewController. I then then tried to set the welcomeViewController as the rootViewController. This still shows the welcomeScreen, but all of the buttons on it do not work. If any one knows how to fix this or a better way to create a welcomeViewController, it would be very much appreciated. Here is the code I am using to show the rootViewController

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"TermsAccepted"]){
        NSLog(@"Second time opening the app");
    }
    else{
        WelcomeViewController *welcomeViewController = [[WelcomeViewController alloc] init];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController = welcomeViewController;
    }
```

To create the UITabBar -

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];


// FeedViewController
feedViewController=[[FeedViewController alloc] init];
feedViewController.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Describe Home_Icon_NormalArtboard-1"];
feedViewController.title = @"Timeline";
feedViewController.tabBarItem.title = nil;

//TodayViewController
TodayViewController *todayViewController = [[TodayViewController alloc] init];
todayViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Today_Icon"];
todayViewController.title = @"Today";
todayViewController.tabBarItem.title = nil;

//CreateViewController
self.createViewController = [[CreateViewController alloc] init];
self.createViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Create_Icon"];
self.createViewController.title = @"Create";
self.createViewController.tabBarItem.title = nil;

//AlertViewController
AlertsViewController *alertsViewController = [[AlertsViewController alloc] init];
alertsViewController.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Alerts_IconArtboard-1"];
alertsViewController.title=@"Alerts";
alertsViewController.tabBarItem.title = nil;

//ProfileViewController
ProfileViewController *profileViewController = [[ProfileViewController alloc] init];
profileViewController.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Profile_IconArtboard-1"];
profileViewController.title=@"Profile";
profileViewController.tabBarItem.title = nil;

NSMutableArray *tabBarViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];


UINavigationController *feedNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:feedViewController];
[tabBarViewControllers addObject:feedNavigationController];
feedNavigationController = nil;

UINavigationController *todayNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:todayViewController];
[tabBarViewControllers addObject:todayNavigationController];
todayNavigationController = nil;

UINavigationController *createNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.createViewController];
[tabBarViewControllers addObject:createNavigationController];
createNavigationController = nil;

UINavigationController *alertsNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:alertsViewController];
[tabBarViewControllers addObject:alertsNavigationController];
alertsNavigationController = nil;

UINavigationController *profileNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:profileViewController];
[tabBarViewControllers addObject:profileNavigationController];
profileNavigationController = nil;

self.tabBarController.viewControllers = tabBarViewControllers;
tabBarViewControllers = nil;

[self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

   if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"TermsAccepted"]){
      NSLog(@"Second time opening the app");
      rootViewController = // Your new main controller
   }
   else
   {
      rootViewController = // Terms and conditions view controller
   }

    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Would this be placed in the app delegate?

Comment: Yup it would, around the area where you configure your UINavigationController, etc

Comment: Updated the question to include more detail

Comment: Thanks, just making sure. All the buttons in the welcomeViewController still do not work tough.

Comment: You haven't posted any code from your WelcomeViewController, that tells me the problem is there.

Comment: So one thing that I think could be a problem is that I have a UITabBar as well, so each View Controller in the UITabBar has it's own Navigation Bar. The code for that is above

Comment: Should I condense all of the table view in to wear I create the feedViewController. I don't need the tableView in the welcome view.